# SCSS @import in Jekyll 2.1

Tags: sass, jekyll

I've this project structure

```
-Project
    -css
        -main.scss
        -_sass/
            -base
            -layout
            -pages
            -vendor
```

Content of my main.scss file.

```
---
---

@import "sass/base/reset";
@import "sass/base/colours";
@import "sass/base/vars-typeplate";
@import "sass/base/typeplate";
```

I've read in Jekyll documentation that in order to work with SCSS statements I've to include  sass: sass_dir: _sass. I suppose I've to add this line over in the _config.yml. But I did it in my and it's still not working. Everytime I try to run jekyll serve. My console shows this message:

```
jekyll 2.1.0 | Error:  File to import not found or unreadable
```

Comment: Maybe you should try and look into this first: http://compass-style.org/ I don't know anything about Jekyll but you need to install sass first (and when you install the compass plugin it automatically installs sass as well + compass is just great)

Comment: I've Sass installed in my machine. Jekyll runs my Sass files fine, although for me to use @import statements, I need to set up some kind of special configuration.

Comment: maybe you could try: @import "reset"; instead of the entire path?

Comment: It gave me the same error.

Comment: Last option I know off (because I know sass, but not Jekyll. Is not to use the layered scss files. Just putt them all in the css folder. Otherwise I can't help you

Answer (score 12):

[Jekyll doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/) says : *If you are using Sass @import statements, you’ll need to ensure that your **sass_dir** is set to the **base directory that contains your Sass files**.*

Then for you it's **css/_sass**.

In your _config.yml, you have :

```
sass:
    sass_dir: css/_sass
```

And in css/mains.cscc

```
---
---

@import "reset";
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 4):

For users landing here who are on Jekyll 3.x here's a simple pattern to follow:

Add files to your `_sass` directory, like:

```
.
├── elements.scss
├── forms.scss
├── layout.scss
├── mixins
│   ├── columns.scss
│   └── flexbox.scss
├── navigation.scss
└── variables.scss
```

There's no need to prefix any of these files with an empty front matter block, and no need to update your Jekyll config.

Then, create a `css` folder under your site root and create a `screen.scss` file like this:

```
---
---
@import "mixins/flexbox";
@import "mixins/columns";
@import "variables";
@import "elements";
@import "layout";
@import "forms";
```

Notice this file *does* use the `---\n--` so it gets picked up by Jekyll and processed properly.

The result will be a file output containing all of your transpiled CSS which you can use in a link tag in your document head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/screen.css">
```

Consult the [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/) for the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Into config.yml

```
sass_dir: css/_sass
```

You must specify the full url.

Answer (score 0):

put the _sass at the root of the project.