# SCSS import fails (Jekyll)

Tags: sass, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to setup Jekyll on GitHub pages. Locally I have no build/execution warnings/errors, even when I use `bundle exec jekyll serve --safe`. But the import command fails on GitHub pages. The error I'm getting back is:

> Your SCSS file `css/main.scss` has an error on line 49: File to import not found or unreadable: base

I have not changed the contents of `main.scss`:

```
// Import partials from `sass_dir` (defaults to `_sass`)
@import
    "base",
    "layout",
    "syntax-highlighting"
;
```

Defining the sass_dir variable explicitly in `_config.yml` doesn't help. Is there a way to debug scss files locally? I have tried using the `sass` command but it doesn't seem to work with scss files.

I know that the problem is with the `@import` part because if I comment it and push the build on GitHub pages no longer fails -- but my blog is ugly :)

Note: I have already tried what's described in [SCSS @import in Jekyll 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587666/scss-import-in-jekyll-2-1) but it didn't get me somewhere.

Comment: With no code, it's difficult to help. Any repository url ?

Comment: https://github.com/faif/faif.github.io/tree/master/blog Jekyll is installed in a subdirectory, if that matters

Comment: I've forked it : same problem. Investigating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, get it ! It was simple.

- Github pages is running from your repository root : `faif.github.io`
- as your `_config.yml` file is in `/blog`, it doesn't see it an takes default settings for everything. eg : path for scss import, is `faif.github.io/_sass` and result in an error, because your files are in `faif.github.io/blog/_sass`.

### First option

Move `_config.yml` at the root and tweak `sass, includes, ...` variables. I don't think it's the best option, but it can certainly be done as nearly everything if configurable in jekyll 3.1.x ([documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)).

### Second option

- Create a **blog** repository
- Clone it
- `git checkout -b gh-pages` because project repositories are published from gh-pages branch only
- Copy your blog folder content in this repository
- Remove your blog folder from faif.github.io repository
- Change `baseurl` to `/blog` in `_config.yml`
- Commit and push

And your done.

Comment: Does the second option mean that I will have two separate repositories? It's a bit more administration overhead but indeed sounds cleaner than moving the configuration file and redefining all paths.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Jekyll is quite stable, until you try to change folder hierarchy. Keep it at the root, and it works just fine.

Comment: Ok, nice. Give me some time to implement it and accept your answer. For now, upvoted :)

Comment: @david-jackquel Have you tried the second option? Because I can't get it to work. I get the same error, even though I moved my blog directory to a different repository: https://github.com/faif/myblog In which repository should the `_config.yml` be?

Comment: @david-jackquel Never mind, thanks. I revisited the settings and it works fine.