# Having problems building github page(SCSS import fails (Jekyll))

Tags: sass, jekyll, github-pages

I was trying to run a github page with Jekyll theme,and the website runs fine locally. However, when I try to urn in on htttps://username.github.io, GitHub cannot build the website.

I got the following error message :

```
Your site is having problems building: Your SCSS file myblog/assets/main.scss has an error on line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: minimaless.
```

The *main.scss* :

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---

@import "minimaless";
```

It seems to be the path to the .scss file expected by GitHub is different from where the Jekyll theme put it. I checked some posts mentioned that I should put the absolute path of .scss in _config.yml file.

It seems to be the path to the .scss file expected by GitHub is different from where the Jekyll theme put it. I checked some posts [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108454/scss-import-fails-jekyll)  mentioned that I should put the absolute path of .scss in the directory of urlbase, which is /myblog. But I am not familiar with ruby, so I am not sure how should I do it.

The folder structure is like this :

myblog/
       - assets/

```
         - main.scss

   - _sasss/

         - minimaless.scss

         - minimaless/

                    - basic.scss

                    - layout.scss

                    - hight-lighting.scss

   - _config.yml
```

This is my GitHub page folder :

https://github.com/Po-Hsuan-Huang/Po-Hsuan-Huang-github.io

Comment: See the typo?  `milimaless.scss`

Comment: @ashmaroli thanks for pointing out. I just changed it. But the type doesn't exist in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be because your source contents are within a subdirectory `myblog`. Try moving all the contents to the root of your repository.

It could also be because of the following in your config file:

```
theme: minimaless
#remote_theme: brettinternet/minimaless
```

`theme: minimaless` is not supported on GitHub Pages. Comment it out.

And finally, `_site` directory should not be checked into version control. Delete it from your repository and then add an entry for it in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it matter is the _site folder is there ? I wonder why Github doesn't read the built html from the _site folder, or just overwrites it. The reason I uploaded the _site is I also changed the html files in it. I made some modification to the theme there because I don't know how to modify the theme in ruby.

Comment: The documentation at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/ may help you in customizing a theme. Good Luck!

Comment: "Try moving all the contents to the root of your repository." This suggestion worked for me. I was using config setting to put the Jekyll source files in a nested directory, but moving them back up to the default root directory got Github Pages to work.